# onClick Action with Label does not work

Tags: swift, uilabel, uitapgesturerecognizer

i want to implement an onClick event with a UILabel.
It prints "hello", so the viewDidLoad() method gets called.
I've connected the UILabel using Storyboard.
I don't see why this code is not working. 
Do you guys see it ?

```
import UIKit


class AlternativeSignUpViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var x: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


        let gestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(AlternativeSignUpViewController.handleTap(_:)))
        x.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
        print("hello")

    }

    func handleTap(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
        print("tapped")
    }


}
```

Comment: Set userInteractionEnabled of label to true.